# Resuable content in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-dialog

I have a view in which I have a DIV which opens up as a JQuery dialog. This DIV has many elements including buttons and static text (No element inside this DIV is assigned any data from any model and it's not making use of any Razor syntax). Now I want to move this DIV to 
another page so as the make it reusable. So that this DIV can be used in other views. What is the best way achieve this? Should I be using MVC user control?

Please Suggest 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the whole DIV in a partial view in your Views/Shared-folder in MVC (or another folder if you want to) . Let's assume you call this file '_DialogView.cshtml'. You can call this partial view from your normal page as a partial view, like this:

```
@Html.RenderPartial('_DialogView')
```

Answer (score 0):

keep the page in a seperate htm. then use jquery.load('mypage.htm'). you can also use hash function in load as well jquery.load('main.htm#divname')

Answer (score 0):

You can also use declarative helpers. See chapter "Reusing @helpers across multiple views" in ScottGu's blog [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx).

**MyHelpers.cshtml**

```
@helper GiveMeInput() 
{
    <input type="text" name"something"/>
}
```

**Usage**

```
@MyHelpers.GiveMeInput()
```